# Add new property:value pair to existing JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an existing JSON object that looks like so:

```
var data = {ID: 123, Name: "test"}
```

Now I want to add in an extra property and value to `data` based on the condition of an inline if statement. The result should look like the following:

```
data = {ID: 123, Name: "test", Surname: "again"}
```

The object above is based on the true condition, while the object below is based on the false condition:

```
data = {ID: 123, Name: "test", Lastname: "again"}
```

Note the change of the property name from Surname to Lastname.
So my question is, how do I add the new property and value into object based on the inline if condition?

I tried the following but obviously that did not work:

```
var data = {ID: 123, Name: "test"};
data = params.Region == 1 ? data.Surname = "again" : data.Lastname = "again"
```

Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data[params.Region == 1 ? 'Surname' : 'Lastname'] = "again"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
params.Region == 1 ? data.Surname = "again" : data.Lastname = "again"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `params.Region` the value `1`. Typo!

`data = (params.Region === 1) ? data.Surname = "again" : data.Lastname = "again"`